# Update users profile without them having to update anything to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update each of my users profiles in my Firestore by adding what device they are using. I have added the following code below into my app.js in componentDidMount Function so that when the app is open it will update, but only really need it to do it once. Will this be constantly making calls to update their profile, I don't want to waste usage and cause lots of writes to Firebase.

```
componentDidMount() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {


      const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        let uid;
        if (user != null) {
          uid = user.uid;
          const db = firebase.firestore();
          db.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
            device: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'IOS' : 'Android',
          }).then(function() {

          })
          .catch(function(error) {
          
          });
        }


    } else {
      this.setState({ device: null, });
    }
  });

  }
```

Comment: The simplest approach is to keep some boolean value on the user device (maybe in async storage or something) and update the firestore only if the boolean is false or null. upon successfully saving the user device info, make this value true to prevent any unwanted firestore calls

Comment: Try To use hook useContext

Comment: nithinpp's approach will wotk for a single device, but what happens if the same user signs in to the app on multiple devices at different times? What do you want the database to show at that time?

Comment: I agree with Frank,what do you expect to happen if your user is changing their device on a weekly basis for example? They should see that they are using the previous device?